# Start an animated script on page from another page

Tags: php, html, node.js

Let me explain what i want to do, i have a spining wheel on a page that can be spin on click but this page will be in a browser source on OBS. So i want to create an other page with a buton that can make the wheel spin.

I already made some search but nothing work for me, i hear about jQuery can do it but i don't really know jQuery :/

I have try to load the script in the page with the button and create an onClick event but nothing change

If anyone here can explain me how it will be nice :)

Edit: There is some code i'm using :

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>roue test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
  </head>
  <body> 
  <div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
    <div id="box" class="box">
      <div class="box1">
        <span class="span1"><b>Jelly Belly</b></span>
        <span class="span2"><b>Nutella</b></span>
        <span class="span3"><b>Miel</b></span>
        <span class="span4"><b>Cacao</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <span class="span1"><b>Rien :)</b></span>
        <span class="span2"><b>Cheddar</b></span>
        <span class="span3"><b>Kinder</b></span>
        <span class="span4"><b>Cornichon</b></span>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <button class="spin" onclick="rotateFunction()"><img src="https://sacul.fr/img/wadd2qi.png" width="80%"></button>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function rotateFunction(){
    var min = 1024;
    var max = 9999;
    var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
}

var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
element.classList.remove('animate');

setTimeout(function(){
    element.classList.add('animate');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Lets us see some code please

Comment: I add the code to the post ;)